# difference between release number and build number in SQl Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms-2016

From [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) I downloaded Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and it was written (16.5.3) but I think it is actually version 13.0.16106.4. When I read the page more carefully I saw the build number for this release: 13.0.16106.4

I took a screenshot:
[screenshot from Microsoft website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LtIR.png)
What is the difference between release number and build number?

Answer (score 0):

The release number is a convenient way to reference the official version that was released to the general population.

The build number refers to where in Microsoft's internal source control and software build process/pipeline the release came from. This is used so that developers can reference the correct point in time for the codebase when investigating/fixing bugs. By the time 13.0.16106.4 is posted on the website, internal developers/users may be on to working with 13.0.16415.2.

Comment: official version is 13.0.16106.4 but Microsoft says release number is 16.5.3. In Management studio you can see version is 13. This not something internal that only Microsoft programmers can see. Your answer did not satisfy me.